# UI elements disappearing out of screen in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code to get the screen width and height of the device so I can set the layout for all the screens.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Now, when I run it on an iPad the value of screenWidth is 768.00000 and that of screenHeight is 1024.00000 which seems about right.

But when I set the frame of a PageControl let's say to something like this -

```
self.pageControl2.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - 40, screenWidth, 20);
```

The page control seems to go outside the screen on the bottom side.

I hardcoded the y-position of the frame to 600 and then only it seems to appear on the bottom of the screen where I intend it to.

Any idea why? I must be doing something wrong...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: write frame value in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and then try

Comment: works.. thanks Bhavin

Comment: Just one more thing if you can, how should I resize images on iPad so they show up in the same way they do on an iPhone. It appears the images i am using are a bit zoomed in on the iPad..

Comment: actually the page control thing just disappeared from the iPhone now

Comment: i just don't understand what you are talking about...and it zoomed because of your frame size...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83195/discussion-between-genaks-and-bhavin).